# Singular ideal of an idealization

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals

Let $S$ be a commutative ring, and let $A$ be a faithful $S$-module. Through idealization, we can make the abelian group $R=S⊕A$ into a commutative ring using the multiplication $(s,a)(s',a')=(ss',sa'+s'a)$. By Problem 16, section D, Chapter 1 of the book *Ring Theory. Nonsingular Rings and Modules* by Kenneth Goodearl, the singular ideal $Z(R)=T⊕A$, where $T=\{s\in S\mid Bs=0$ for some essential submodule $B$ of $A$}. My question:

> If $z\in Z(S)$, the singular ideal of $S$, and $a\in A$ what condition may be imposed on $z$ and/or $a$ to guarantee that $(z,a)\in Z(R)$?

From $z\in Z(S)$ we get that the annihilator ideal  of $z$ in $S$ is essential in $S$ meaning that its intersection with any nonzero ideal of $S$ is nonzero; and I search for an essential submodule $B$ of $A$ which annihilates the element $z$. But I can't get any good idea for introducing $B$. Thanks for any cooperation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have asked,
*If $z\in Z(S)$, the singular ideal of $S$,
and $a\in A$, what condition may be imposed on
$z$ and/or $a$ to guarantee that $(z,a)\in Z(R)$?*

From the exercise, $Z(R)=T\oplus A$. Thus $(z,a)\in Z(R)=T\oplus A$ iff
$z\in T$. This is the correct
restriction on $z$ and there is no restriction on $a$.

Since you are asking about the additional effect of assuming $z\in Z(S)$,
it may be that you want to know how $Z(S)$ and $T$ are related.
Here are some examples that show that they are not very related.

1. $S = \mathbb Z$, $A = \bigoplus_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$.
   In this example, $A$ is a faithful $S$-module,
   $Z(S) = (0)$, and $T = p\mathbb Z$.
   Therefore $T$ contains $Z(S)$ and depends on $p$,
   while $Z(S)$ does not depend on $p$.
2. $S$ is a commutative ring whose singular ideal properly
   contains the nilradical,
   $A=S\oplus \left(\bigoplus_{P\lhd S, P\;\textrm{prime}} S/P\right)$.
   In this example, $A$ is a faithful $S$-module
   because $S$ is a summand of $A$. Any element that
   lies outside some prime ideal $P$ cannot lie
   in $T$ because $S/P$ is a summand of $A$. Thus $T$ must
   equal the nilradical, which is properly contained inside $Z(S)$.